# Is it possible to compute intrinsic and extrinsic camera parameters from a given camera projection matrix?

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration

If I have a 3x4 camera projection matrix, can I compute all or just some of the individual intrinsic and extrinsic camera parameters, i.e., focal length, principal point coordinates, rotation angles (roll, yaw and tilt), and translation vector? If yes, what are the formula?

Is there any tool in OpenCV/OpenGL/MATLAB that could help me do so?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You proceed by decomposing your projection matrix into the product of an upper triangular one and an orthogonal one. You can google search for RQ-decomposition for details. A nice summary is [here](https://ksimek.github.io/2012/08/14/decompose/).